# JavaFX 8: Blank scene after monitor out of standby

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I'm having a weird issue with JavaFX (jdk8, build 117): once the monitor resumes from standby the JavaFX stage/scene is blank.

I've tried minimizing/resizing the window but the contents are no longer displayed. I'm using a simple scene with a StackPane.

```
    root = new StackPane();
    root.setBackground(null);
    scene = new Scene(root, Color.BLACK);
    stage.setScene(scene);

    ProgressIndicator piLoader = new ProgressIndicator();
    piLoader.setMaxSize(32d, 32d);
    root.getChildren().add(piLoader);

    stage.show();
```

I've tried searching for a known bug or a previous report but could not find any.

Comment: Fixed the build number. Thanks!

Comment: If your program really is that simple then it's probably a bug which you should file on Jira.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDK8 is still very much in flux & marked as an early access release, so issues like this should be expected. I've just tested it on JDK8 built b121 (Win8 64bit & Ubuntu 13.10 64bit) and it appears to be fine.

Update your JDK version to the latest & see if that resolves the issue for you.

UPDATE: Here's a full stock-standard example that works without problem for me, monitor goes into sleep mode & comes back without any display issues. 'Sleep mode' is the only option Windows 8 is giving me, so not 'Standby' as you're referring to. Which OS are you using?

```
package helloworld;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setBackground(null);
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        ProgressIndicator piLoader = new ProgressIndicator();
        piLoader.setMaxSize(32d, 32d);
        root.getChildren().add(piLoader);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250, Color.BLACK);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Will try again with the latest JDK and come back with a reply.

Comment: Updated to build 123 and tried again. The scene is not completely blank this time. Controls are repainted, just the background is black. A window resize solves that too.

Comment: Looks like there is still work in progress with respect to this.

Comment: If you can break it down to just a couple of lines of code, post it here and I'll test it. I've got an Ubuntu & Win8 machine, not seeing the same issue as you have.

Comment: I'm still getting this issue with the official release. Happens to SceneBuilder and Ensemble also.

Comment: Still not getting the same effect, goes into standby, comes out, everything still there. Could you please post a full sample app that does not work for you. I'm posting a full sample app that does work - below - see if that has the same issue for you or not.

Comment: @simsam7 I'm using Windows 7. Your example/app should trigger the problem you will only need for the monitor to enter sleep mode (not just go blank).Switched to Ubuntu for my development and haven't noticed the issue anymore. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: My laptop is connected to several monitors via a dock. When I unplug it, and go mobile, all JavaFX applications I have running are rendered inoperable with either blank scenes or are seemingly unresponsive. Resizing and moving the window doesn't help. This happens with Scenebuilder, Ensemble, JFoenix sample app and my own applications. Does anyone know if any defects have been reported to Oracle? I haven't found any. There is one that [refers to a situation where the monitor goes to sleep](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8174992), but it's currently unresolved.